# django form view show error or not

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm making a little personal project using Django framework and I get one question while making login view with django form.

I was struggled to show form error messages in my template, and I found a cause in my view.

This is view that showing error message

```
def login_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.login(request)
        return redirect('/')
else:
    form = LoginForm()
context = {
    'form': form,
}
return render(request, 'member/login.html', context=context)
```

another view that dosen't showing error message

```
def login_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.login(request)
        return redirect('/')
form = LoginForm()
context = {
    'form': form,
}
return render(request, 'member/login.html', context=context)
```

and this is my template

```
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.username}}
{{ form.password }}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<button id="login-btn" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">login</button>
```

The difference is just using `else`phrase or not in view. 
I think whether using `else`phrase or not, there two views have logically same result... I don't understand difference of those two views.

Is there any clue to understand the differece of those two views?..

Thanks

Comment: what should I do, if I found answer by my self....

Comment: If the form has errors, is_valid returns False and `LoginForm(request.POST)` is bounded form. In the first view `render` is return with `LoginForm(request.POST)` that is bounded form ,but In second view return render with unbounded new form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the POST form by defining the form at the end. Load the blank form first

```
def login_view(request):

    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.login(request)
            return redirect('/')

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'member/login.html', context=context)
```